# If current user isn't in role required by [Authorize], can I automatically redirect them?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, authorize-attribute

In the ASP.NET MVC site I am building, I have some methods where the users who use them have to be in a certain role (as it happens, if they're not, it means that they're suspended from the site). To accomplish this, I'm using the `[Authorize(Roles="RoleName")]` attribute without any difficulties.

However, I don't quite understand what happens to users who don't pass that `[Authorize]` check? What are they shown?

I want to redirect suspended users to a different Action if they try to use these methods. For now, I've been using a blank `[Authorize]` attribute (without any roles specified) and then checking in the Action code whether the user is part of the Role or not.

My approach feels like a code smell to me. **Is it possible to specify what to show to a user (or where to redirect them to) if they don't pass the `[Authorize]` check?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated on the [AuthorizeAttribute MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx):

> If an unauthorized user tries to
>   access a method that is marked with
>   the Authorize attribute, the MVC
>   framework returns a 401 HTTP status
>   code. If the site is configured to use
>   ASP.NET forms authentication, the 401
>   status code causes the browser to
>   redirect the user to the login page.

If you're using forms authentication and want to redirect to the login page, you have nothing to do. Otherwise implement your own `IAuthorizationFilter` to do the redirection.

**Edit**: see [this blog post](http://blog.wekeroad.com/blog/aspnet-mvc-securing-your-controller-actions/) that basically reimplement the AuthorizeAttribute manually, with custom redirection.

Comment: How does it redirect the user to the login page if the user is already logged in (but doesn't have sufficient privileges)? Also, how can I implement my own IAuthorizationFilter? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to implement your own IAuthorizationFilter I believe you should be able to override the default behavior of the Authorize attribute. Just inherit and override the [HandleUnauthorizedRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.handleunauthorizedrequest.aspx) method. Granted you'll still need a way to determine if the user failed due to not being logged in vs not having the right permissions. It may be cleaner just to write your own authorization filter.